# Invoking an external process with a different user in java

Tags: java, exec

We have a java application running as a windows service. A particular functionality needs to execute a binary but with a different user then which started the application.

Is there any way by which we can invoke an exe with 'Run as a different user' style.

I checked API of ProcessBuilder but didn't found anything related to user. Is there any 3rd party tool to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [PSExec](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-gb/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx) to execute processes as a different user. The command line looks like:

```
psexec.exe -u username -p password mybinary.exe
```

You can then use ProcessBuilder to build the command around this.

**Edit:** here is an example of how you can do it:

```
public int startProcess(String username, String password, 
        String executable, String... args) throws IOException {

    final String psexec = "C:\\PsTools\\psexec.exe"; //psexec location

    //Build the command line
    List<String> command = new LinkedList<String>();
    command.add(psexec);

    if(username != null) {
        command.add("-u");
        command.add(username);
        command.add("-p");
        command.add(password);
    }

    command.add(executable);
    command.addAll(Arrays.asList(args));

    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
    Process process = builder.start();

    int returnCode;

    try {
        returnCode = process.waitFor();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        returnCode = 1;
    }

    return returnCode;
}
```

You can then use it like this:

```
startProcess("Bob", "Password", "Notepad.exe", "C:\\myfile.txt");
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can use the `runas` DOS command in a pinch, if you can't find something else. (Type `runas` in a dos prompt for usage info.)

Edit: Unfortunately, according to a note [here](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-0014.html) this apparently won't work from a service. :/ You might be able to create a small separate wrapper app that you could invoke which would then invoke the binary with `runas`, though.

Comment: But there is no way to specify the password.