# Java application permissions

Tags: java, permissions, subprocess

Does the java application permissions extends for created processes? i.e. if application hasn't permissions to create file and I'm running someprogram.exe from this application, then is it restricted too?

If no then how can I restrict created processes? Another thing I want to do is to restrict the memory used by subprocess. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not absolute clear to me, what kind of permissions you're talking about.

The Java security settings are *per application* restrictions. They affect java code that runs inside one java virtual machine. If you call an executable, than that executable will not inherit those permissions.

Other permissions are *per user* permission. So if *you* don't have the permission to create a file in a certain folder, then the Java application that you started won't have the permission and any executable started from the java vm won't have permission too.

Answer (score 0):

You can restrict the memory of the sub process just like any normal java app, for ex:

```
java -Xmx16m -XX:MaxPermSize=128m
```

On the other hand I believe the permissions are the same as the user that started the application, just like any *nix behaviour. When you spawn the new process you can probably change the user in witch that process is started but depends on implementation.

I don't have ref to this so I might be wrong but I don's see why this behaviour would be any different in any desktop app.

Comment: Thanks! If anyone interested, I found useful this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409852/invoking-an-external-process-with-a-different-user-in-java. But not quite well understand how MaxPermSize option can help me to restrict sub process's memory