# Java Runtime Exec with specific process privilege on Android

Tags: java, android

Java Runtime [exec()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20java.io.File)) function runs the command in a separate process. My question is that on a Android system is it possible to control the effective uid of the process created by Runtime exec() ?

Comment: What is it you want to do and why?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Invoking an external process with a different user in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409852/invoking-an-external-process-with-a-different-user-in-java) You can use similar tactics on Linux with sudo.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Need to run a untrusted binary with limited privilege from an app.

Comment: Voting that this is not a duplicate because Windows and DOS commands will be little help on Android.

Comment: @jake Show your research.